# Powershell Like Wildcard issue

Tags: powershell, wildcard

Can't get this wildcard comparison to work, what am I doing wrong? 
I can only get:

> Windows Server 2016
>
> Windows 10 Enterprise x64

For instance, I can't get

> Windows 10 Enterprise X64 1709 ?

how come? 
I also get only 2 hints, it should give me 5

> **Output of `$TaskSequence.name` is**
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2 X64
>
> Windows 10 Enterprise x64 USMT Hardlinks
>
> Windows 10 Enterprise x64 1703 en-US
>
> Windows Server 2016
>
> Windows 10 Enterprise x64 USMT Full OS
>
> Windows 10 Enterprise x64
>
> Windows 7
>
> **Output of `$ImagePackage.name` is**
>
> Windows Server 2016 x64
>
> Windows 10 Enterprise x64

```
$SiteCode = "PS1"
    $SiteServer = "SRVSCCM01"
    $TaskSequence = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_TaskSequencePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer)
    $ImagePackage = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_ImagePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer)
    Foreach($Task in $TaskSequence){
        Foreach($Image in $ImagePackage){ 
            if($Task.Name -like "*$($Image.Name)*" -or $Image.Name -like "*$($Task.Name)*"){ 
                $Task.name

            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: If i create a new Task sequence and call it Windows 10 Enterprise x64, i get a match on both Windows server and Windows 10 Enterprise.. But i would like it to match  TS with Windows 10 Enterprise x64 1709 also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm really studpid, sometimes you just need to look at your code from another angle, i was doing a

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_TaskSequencePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer| where-object {$_.Name -like "*$($Task.Name)*"   }
```

inside the foreach loop, which defeats the purpose, so i just added another foreach, and now it all works perfectly as intended - thanks for all your sugestions

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things a little bit.  I'm assuming your WMI calls are returning arrays of objects with this example:

```
$Output = @()
$Output += $TaskSequence.Name | Where-Object { $ImagePackage.Name -like "*$_*" }
$Output += $ImagePackage.Name | Where-Object { $TaskSequence.Name -like "*$_*" }
```

But ultimately, your comparisons are failing because your logic is off.  Are you looking for wildcard comparisons or equality?

---

Edit: got it working as anticipated with the following-

```
Foreach ($Task in $TaskSequence)
{
    Foreach ($Image in $ImagePackage)
    { 
        If ($Task.Name -like "*$($Image.Name)*")
        {
            $Task.Name
        }
        ElseIf ($Image.Name -like "*$($Task.Name)*")
        {
            $Image.Name
        }
    }
}
```

You were only outputting one side of the equation every time

Comment: Wildcard, i need to match Imagepackage with Tasksequence names, based on wildcard, as The Image begins with fx Windows 10 x64, but the Tasksequence can be fx Build and Capture Windows 10 x64

Your suggestion also only gives me 2 hints

Answer (score 0):

I'd offer another solution. Using a RegEx match, and joining the opposite array as the match pattern.

```
$SiteCode = "PS1"
$SiteServer = "SRVSCCM01"
$TaskSequence = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_TaskSequencePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer)
$ImagePackage = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\SMS\site_$($SiteCode)" -Class SMS_ImagePackage -ComputerName $SiteServer)
$TaskPattern = ($TaskSequence.Name|%{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join '|'
$ImagePattern = ($ImagePackage.Name|%{[regex]::escape($_)}) -join '|'
$TaskSequence.Name|?{$_ -match $ImagePattern}
$ImagePackage.Name|?{$_ -match $TaskPattern}
```

Plus this avoids nested loops, which can get out of hand really fast. This will in fact get you 6 results, not 5 as you suggested, since 'Windows 10 Enterprise x64' is in both sets.

**Edit:** So if you are not seeing the results you expect I suspect that you have unaccounted for whitespace. Try trimming your strings when you generate the RegEx patterns, and see if that makes a difference.

```
$TaskPattern = ($TaskSequence.Name|%{[regex]::escape($_.Trim())}) -join '|'
$ImagePattern = ($ImagePackage.Name|%{[regex]::escape($_.Trim())}) -join '|'
```

Comment: Sorry, but i only get 2 hints.. i edited the main code, and included all the code

Comment: `$TaskSequence.Name|?{$_ -match $ImagePattern}` Does got give any hints

Comment: Try the update, and if it still fails maybe you can post what you get for `$ImagePattern`.